# Create snap that has all built applications exposed

Tags: packaging, snap

I am building a snap that has a package that build 7 tools in the `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` and would like to expose all of them. Is there a way to wildcard the the app command? I have done this already with filesets and stage being `$binaries` and snap being `$binaries`.

Thanks

Comment: Thoughts from anyone who has build snap packages with a tool suite?